# Random quote generator repeats the same quotes, why?

Tags: ruby, shoes

Good day to everyone! There is a quote generator made with Shoes.

```
    @think.click do
        @noun_nominative.shuffle
        @base.shuffle
        @thought.replace(@base.sample)
    end

    @noun_nominative = 
        [
            "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4",
            "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8"
        ]
    @noun_accusative = 
        [
            "word1", "word2", "word3"
        ]
    @base =
        [
        @noun_nominative.sample.capitalize + "regular quote",
        "Regular quote" + @noun_nominative.sample,
        "Regular quote" + @noun_accusative.sample,
        "Regular quote" + @noun_accusative.sample,
        @noun_nominative.sample.capitalize + "regular quote",
        "And another one base for a quote"
        ]
```

It simply replaces phrases in *base* array with random words from *noun_nominative* and *noun_accusative*, showing a new quote every time button "think" is clicked.

The program should make a brand new quote with every click, however, it keeps showing the same phrases which were generated once. How could I make it regenerate the quotes without reopening the program?

Thank you for answering!

Comment: May be you need to replace `shuffle` with `shuffle!`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh: no, it's another thing.

Comment: It looks like you sample for nouns in the assignment to `@base`, which only happens once. So you get the same quote since you never reassign that variable in `@think.click`

Comment: Your `shuffle` is redundant, btw. Random choice is already achieved by `sample`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate random quote on each click, rather than pre-generating them at app startup. This should be the laziest change to do what you want:

```
def generate_random_quote(nominative, accusative)
  all_generated_quotes = [
    nominative.sample.capitalize + " - это всякий, кто стремится убить тебя, неважно на чьей он стороне.",
    "Иногда " + nominative.sample + " не попадает в " + accusative.sample + ", но " + nominative.sample + " не может промахнуться.",
    "Нет ничего труднее, чем гибнуть, не платя смертью за " + accusative.sample + ".",
    "Индивидуумы могут составлять " + accusative.sample + ", но только институты могут создать " + accusative.sample + ".",
    nominative.sample.capitalize + " - это тот человек, который знает о вас все и не перестает при этом любить вас.",
    "Трудно себе представить, что сталось бы с человеком, живи он в государстве, населенном литературными героями."
  ]

  all_generated_quotes.sample
end

@think.click do
  freshly_baked_random_quote = generate_random_quote(@noun_nominative, @noun_accusative)
  @thought.replace(freshly_baked_random_quote)
end
```

It is, of course, rather wasteful. It generates all possible quotes and discards all but one. If that's a concern, fixing that would be your homework. :)

Comment: @RemmiBogomolova: you're welcome. Don't stop here, though. Try to do the suggested improvement. Good practice.